# "when" with regex doesn't work jenkins pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I am trying to ignore a stage in Jenkins pipeline when the tag of the release dosn't match.
It doesn't work, it will continue to the steps even when the tag does not match.

I need to run the pipeline only for tags that much the following regex: "*rc*"

The Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            when { tag pattern: "*rc*", comparator: "REGEXP" }
            steps {
                sh "echo 'DO SOMETHING'"
            }
    }
```

I tried to change the regex:
`

```
when { tag pattern: "/(.*)rc(.*)/", comparator: "REGEXP" }
```

Comment: Did you try `.*rc.*` or just `rc`

Comment: Yes, I did try it. didn't help @Thefourthbird

Comment: do you have some sample input which you could show, seeing how you don't have word boundaries, your regex would also match something containing `noarch`

Comment: @akash An example of the input I am expecting to get is `5.0.0rc1`.
I know that my regex would also match other outputs, but yet I do not understand why does the when condition didn't work :(